# Не могу создать новый модуль в Maven проекте на IntellijIDEA 15

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Есть  OSGI проект на мавене, много модулей и тд. Все работает. Поставил IntellijIDEA 15 и запустил там проет. все с первого раза клево открылось. работал все норм. Сейчас пытаюсь создать новый модуль в проекте и получаю ошибку

```
Failed to create a Maven project
'C:/gitProjects/mayProj/pom.xml' already exists in VFS
```

Создаю модуль в корне проекта. так вот после ошибки создается файл  `iml` с именем создаваемого модуля. но самого модуля нет.

Открываем проект на 14 идеи - все создается нормально. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Мне помогло решение по ссылке! [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763928/error-when-i-tried-create-new-maven-module-in-intellijide-15)